# Homology of space resulting from gluing boundaries of two solid tori via certain map

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'd really appreciate some hints or suggestions on how to approach the following problem:

> Let $D^2$ be the unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$, and let $S^1 = \partial D^2$. Let $ X = D^2 \times S^1 \times \{0,1\}/\sim$, where $$(x,y,0) \sim (xy^5, y, 1)$$ for all $x,y \in S^1$. Compute the homology groups of $X$.

I've done a similar problem that asked to compute the homology of two solid tori with their boundaries identified via the identity mapping, which used Mayer-Vietoris. My first thought was to try that here as well, but I'm having a hard time visualizing what the decomposition should be. I'm kind of drawing a blank on how to proceed. Does anybody have any hints or advice?

Comment: This is the approach I tried, but I'm not sure if I was visualizing the intersection correctly. Would it just be (homotopy equivalent) to $S^1 \times S^1$? And if so, I was also unsure about my computation of the map $H_1(S^1 \times S^1) \to H_1(U) \oplus H_1(V)$. I'm thinking it might be given in matrix form by  $ \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\5&1\end{bmatrix}$, but I'm quite uncertain. Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on how computing the intersections (of the inclusions of the generators of $H_1(S^1 \times S^1)?)$ allows you to determine the induced map on homology? I think I am unfamiliar with this method. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Let $f(x, y) = (xy^5, y)$. One of the maps $S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1 \times D^2$ is the standard inclusion $i$ and the other one is $i \circ f$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi:S^1\times S^1\to S^1\times S^1$ denote the homeomorphism $(x,y)\mapsto(xy^5,y)$ and let $Z$ denote our space. We can apply the following general fact (which follows the discussion in comments):

> Let $(X,A)$ be a good pair and $\phi:A\to Y$ an embedding such that $(Y,\phi(A))$ is a good pair. Let $Z$ be the pushout of $X\overset{\iota}{\leftarrow}A\overset{\phi}{\rightarrow}Y$ (... that's the quotient of $X\sqcup Y$ via the relation $a\sim\phi(a))$, where $\iota$ is inclusion.
>
> Then there is a long exact sequence: $$\cdots\to H_{n+1}(Z)\to H_n(A)\overset{\langle\iota_\ast,\phi_\ast\rangle}{\longrightarrow}H_n(X)\oplus H_n(Y)\to H_n(Z)\to\cdots$$

Here a "good pair" is a pair $(C,D)$ where $D$ is a nonempty subspace of $C$ and there exists an open neighbourhood of $D$ which strongly deformation retracts onto $D$ (within $C$).

This is explained below. Let's first apply it to the problem at hand. Here $X=D^2\times S^1=Y$ and $A=S^1\times S^1$. $\phi$ is the automorphism of $A$, $(x,y)\mapsto(xy^5,y)$. Since $H_n(A),H_n(X),H_n(Y)$ are all zero in degree $\ge3$ here, the sequence proves $H_n(Z)\cong0$ for all $n\ge4$, and since $Z$ is obviously path connected $H_0(Z)\cong\Bbb Z$. The interesting fragment is this: $$\cdots\to0\to H_3(Z)\to\Bbb Z\to0\to H_2(Z)\to\Bbb Z^2\to\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z\to H_1(Z)\to\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z\to\cdots$$

This automatically gives $H_3(Z)\cong\Bbb Z$. The map $\Bbb Z^2\to\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z$ has first projection the map induced by $\iota:S^1\times S^1\to D^2\times S^1$, which (in light of $D^2\simeq\{\ast\}$) takes $(x,y)\to y$ using the description of the generators of the torus and circle homology. The second projection is more interesting. The first generator of the torus homology is (can be taken to be) a loop in some $S^1\times\{z_0\}$ which $\phi$ takes to another loop in $S^1\times\{z_0\}\subseteq D^2\times\{z_0\}$ and this contracts down to zero in homology; however, the second generator which "is" some loop in $\{z_0\}\times S^1$ is taken to itself by $\phi$, so we find $\phi_\ast(x,y)=y$. Overall the map $\Bbb Z^2\to\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z$ is just $(x,y)\mapsto(y,y)$. The kernel of this map is $\Bbb Z\oplus0\cong\Bbb Z$, so $H_2(Z)\cong\Bbb Z$.

The cokernel is $\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z/(1,1)\Bbb Z\cong\Bbb Z$. At the end of that fragment there is a map $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z$ which similarly runs $x\mapsto(x,x)$, with trivial kernel. Showing $H_1(Z)\cong\Bbb Z$.

Overall: $$H_n(Z)\cong\begin{cases}\Bbb Z&n=0,1,2,3\\0&n\ge4\end{cases}$$

---

To see this, take open neighbourhoods $V,W$ of $A,\phi(A)$ as in the statement of good pair and write $q:X\sqcup Y\twoheadrightarrow Z$ for the quotient map. $V':=q(V\cup Y)$ and $W':=q(X\cup W)$ define open neighbourhoods of $q(A)$ and $V'\cup W'=Z$. There is a Mayer-Vietoris sequence: $$\cdots\to H_{n+1}(Z)\to H_n(V'\cap W')\to H_n(V')\oplus H_n(W')\to H_n(Z)\to\cdots$$

The deformation of $V$ onto $A$ makes $V'$ deform onto $q(Y)\cong Y$. That $q$ is a homeomorphism $Y\to q(Y)$ relies on $\phi$ being an embedding; similarly $q(X)\cong X$ and $W'\simeq X$. $V'\cap W'$ deforms from both sides, if you like, onto $q(A)\cong A$. This allows for identifications $H_n(V'\cap W')\cong H_n(A)$ and $H_n(V')\cong H_n(Y)$, $H_n(W')\cong H_n(X)$.

Under these, what does $H_n(V'\cap W')\to H_n(V')$ look like as a map $H_n(A)\to H_n(Y)$? It is the composite: $$H_n(A)\to H_n(q(A))=H_n(q(\phi(A)))\to H_n(q(Y))\cong H_n(Y)\\=H_n(A)\to H_n(Y)\to H_n(q(Y))\cong H_n(Y)$$Which is just $\phi_\ast:H_n(A)\to H_n(Y)$. Similarly the map $H_n(V'\cap W')\to H_n(W')$ corresponds to $\iota_\ast:H_n(A)\to H_n(X)$, giving the claim.